# Can't create app package in uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I was creating app packages for my uwp project. It was creating well. But today itself it shows an error

Error       ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0.Net.NetNative\15.0.24211\x64\ilc\tools\Gatekeeper.exe @"C:\Users\xxxx\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Test1\Test1\obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\gkargs.rsp"' returned exit code -1073741819    Test1   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0.Net.NetNative\15.0.24211\x64\ilc\IlcInternals.targets

What is this and how to resolve it?

Comment: try to clean it.

Comment: tried cleaning and rebuilding. no effect

Comment: Have you ever modified your project? Recently, Windows recently released a new version, need update Visual Studio to 15.4, what is the version of your VS, have you try to update, then check if it works for you?

Comment: I'am using V15.1